# Passing multiple models to view problem spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I have a form for entering a City (mesto) and I don't know how to pass a list of Countries and Regions (separate Entities) to that city view (I want a dropdown list so i could select country and region from database when entering a new city). I have a problem to do that.

Here is a initial controller method and view before adding lists and it works

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/dodaj")
        public String prikaziForm(Model theModel) {

    Mesto mesto = new Mesto();

    int a = 0;
    a = mestoService.sledeciSlBroj();
    mesto.setSifra(a);  
    theModel.addAttribute("mesto", mesto);

    return "mesto-form";
 }
```

View:

```
    <form:form action="sacuvaj" modelAttribute="mesto" method="POST">
    <form:hidden path="sifra" />
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Sifra:</label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="sifra" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label>Naziv:</label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="naziv" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label>Regija:</label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="regija.sifra" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label>Drzava:</label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="drzava.sifra" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label>Postanski broj:</label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="posBroj" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label></label></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Sacuvaj" class="save" /></td>
                </tr>


            </tbody>
        </table>


    </form:form>
```

After unsuccessful attempt of adding lists

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/dodaj")
public String prikaziForm(Model theModel) {

    Mesto mesto = new Mesto();

    int a = 0;
    a = mestoService.sledeciSlBroj();
    mesto.setSifra(a);  
    List<Regija> regije = regijaService.getRegije();
    List<Drzava> drzave = drzavaService.getDrzave();
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("mesto", mesto);
    model.put("regije", regije);
    model.put("drzave", drzave);

    theModel.addAttribute("model", model);

    return "mesto-form";
}
```

View:

```
    <form:form action="sacuvaj" modelAttribute="model" method="POST">
    <form:hidden path="mesto.sifra" />
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Sifra:</label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="mesto.sifra" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label>Naziv:</label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="mesto.naziv" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label>Regija:</label></td>
                    <form:select path = "regije.naziv">
                    <form:option value = "NONE" label = "Select"/>
                    <form:options items = "${regije.naziv}" />
                    </form:select> 
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <form:select path = "drzave.naziv">
                    <form:option value = "NONE" label = "Select"/>
                    <form:options items = "${drzave.naziv}" />
                    </form:select> 
                </tr>               
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Postanski broj:</label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="mesto.posBroj" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label></label></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Sacuvaj" class="save" /></td>
                </tr>


            </tbody>
        </table>


    </form:form>
```

Mesto:

```
   package com.springdemo.komitent.entity;

  import javax.persistence.Column;
  import javax.persistence.Entity;
  import javax.persistence.Id;
  import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
  import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
  import javax.persistence.Table;

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "mesto")
 public class Mesto {

@Id
@Column(name = "SIFRA")
private int sifra;

@Column(name = "NAZIV")
private String naziv;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "DRZAVA", nullable = true)
private Drzava drzava;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "REGIJA", nullable = true)
private Regija regija;

@Column(name = "POSTANSKIBROJ")
private int posBroj;



 public Mesto(int sifra, String naziv, Drzava drzava, Regija regija, int 
  posBroj) {
    super();
    this.sifra = sifra;
    this.naziv = naziv;
    this.drzava = drzava;
    this.regija = regija;
    this.posBroj = posBroj;
}

public Mesto () {}

public int getSifra() {
    return sifra;
}


public void setSifra(int sifra) {
    this.sifra = sifra;
}


public String getNaziv() {
    return naziv;
}


public void setNaziv(String naziv) {
    this.naziv = naziv;
}

public Drzava getDrzava() {
    return drzava;
}

public void setDrzava(Drzava drzava) {
    this.drzava = drzava;
}

public Regija getRegija() {
    return regija;
}

public void setRegija(Regija regija) {
    this.regija = regija;
}

public int getPosBroj() {
    return posBroj;
}


public void setPosBroj(int posBroj) {
    this.posBroj = posBroj;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Mesto [sifra=" + sifra + ", naziv=" + naziv + ", drzava=" + drzava + ", regija=" + regija + ", posBroj="
            + posBroj + "]";
 }

}
```

I get this error

**SEVERE: Invalid property 'mesto' of bean class [java.util.HashMap]: Bean property 'mesto' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'mesto' of bean class [java.util.HashMap]: Bean property 'mesto' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getNestedPropertyAccessor(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:839)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyAccessorForPropertyPath(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:816)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:610)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:148)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag.writeTagContent(HiddenInputTag.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:83)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.mesto_002dform_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fhidden_005f0(mesto_002dform_jsp.java:462)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.mesto_002dform_jsp._jspService(mesto_002dform_jsp.java:196)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1371)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)**

I'm not passing the model correctly, I know that, and I need help to do it right.

Comment: Add your Mesto and also post full error

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: Don't use hashmap. Directly add your objects to model.theModel.addAttribute("mesto", mesto);theModel.addAttribute("regije",regije);

Comment: Can you, please, take a look at my View and label REGIJA. How can I now insert this attribute ("regije", regije) in my drop-down list. How would you have done it?